# Is there a way to call mouse up event manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I hold the mouse button I need to call the mouse up event manually(without involving any mouse click). How to do that?

Comment: `$el.mouseup()`

Comment: Although you can do that, it is rarely a good practice. Consider wrapping the whole event handler in a function and calling the function instead, while the mouse even will just call the wrapper.

Comment: Yes  `$( "#id" ).mouseup();` is working.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('yourElementSelector').trigger('mouseUp');
```

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: yes I did, on an older jQuery though... and it worked like a charm, it triggered the function I have bound to the mouseUp event